Firebase Emulator UI (Firestore) does not show documents in a subcollection when docID has integers within parentheses
Current Structure:
Root
|
--- MainCollection [collection]
|     |
|     --- doc(1234) [document]
|            |
|            --- SubCollection [collection] <- not showing!
|     |
|     --- (123456) [document]
|            |
|            --- SubCollection [collection] <- not showing!
|     |
|     --- (123456 [document]
|            |
|            --- SubCollection [collection] <- showing!


Notice the document IDs, when the document ID has integers within parentheses it does not expand.
The SubCollection under docID "(123456)" or docID "doc(1234)" does not expand.

The above behaviour only happens in the Emulator UI, I can access all documents from the client-side code.

Can you please provide a screenshot when you click on MainCollection/(123456)/SubCollection?

@AlexMamo The second screenshot provided is taken after clicking MainCollection/(123456)/SubCollection

I replicated your issue and I'm also unable to open subcollections if the document has parentheses.

And I found there has been a github issue which is still open for a long time. I suggest you to either add your concern there in the github issue or to raise a new one at same link. Or else you can contact the firebase team by raising a bug from here.
